# Не могу установить APIs/SDKs для 2.1 и 2.2.

Tags: android-sdk, sdk

Путаюсь установить SDKs для 2.1 or 2.2 в Eclipse, но получаю вот такие вот эроры:

> File not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\android-16_r03.zip (Отказано в доступе)

как с этим бороться?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

После скитаний по просторам инета все-таки нашел решение проблемы:
Пуск -> And roid SDK Manager -> правая кнопка мыши -> запустить от имени администратора

Comment: Стоит отметить, что это проблема Windows 7 и, возможно, windows 8

Comment: насчет 8-ки не знаю, у самого 7-ка

Comment: Ну, я к тому, что под линуксом и ХР именно такая проблема невозможна.